# Adding spaces between strings in Ruby

Tags: ruby

```
file = File.new("pastie.rb", "r")
    while (line = file.gets)
       labwords = print line.split.first 
    end
file.close
```

How do I add spaces between the strings? Right now the output is one giant string. I figure I need to use .join or .inject somehow, but my Ruby syntax skills are poor right now, I am still a  beginner. I also need to skip indented spaces in the files paragraph. But I have no clue how to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting something to the result of a `print` is a bit messy. You probably don't mean to do that. Instead, try:

```
labwords = line.split

print labwords.join(' ')
```

If you want to skip certain lines, this is the pattern:

```
while (line = file.gets)
  # Skip this line if the first character is a space
  next if (line[0,1] == " ")

  # ... Rest of code
end
```

You can also clean up that `File.new` call like this:

```
File.open('pastie.rb', 'r') do |file|
  # ... Use file normally
end
```

That will close it for you automatically.

Comment: And `File.foreach(...)` would be even cleaner than `File.open`.

Comment: I keep getting "undefined method 'join' for "placeholder":String (NoMethodError).

Comment: The result of `line.split` should be an array. If you're getting a string you've done something else to it. What code produces that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `strip` to remove all the white space.

```
file = File.new("pastie.rb", "r")
lines = []
file.each_line do |line|
   lines << line.strip.split
end
file.close
puts lines.map { |line| line.join(" ") }.join(" ")
```